# Writing Excel to CSV file, how can I use another delimiter?

Tags: python

So im using the following script to export a excel file to csv.

```
import csv
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('excel.xlsm')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    if sheet.name == "Database":
        with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            for row in range(sheet.nrows):
                out = []
                for cell in sheet.row_values(row):
                    if isinstance(cell, float):
                        out.append(cell)
                    else:
                        out.append(unicode(cell).encode('utf8'))
                writer.writerow(out)
```

So far everything it's working good. but I would like the csv file to be created with `;` as a delimiter for each cell instead of the `,` How can I acheive this?

instead of `cell1,cell2,` I want the output to become `cell1;cell2;`

**(Edit) Solution**

set the delimiter when initiating csv.writer `writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")`

Comment: `csv` is comma-separated values, and it is called that way for a reason. To achieve what you want, try directly writing as a text file. you can keep the csv extension if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: I found the solution to my question by changing the delimiter when initating the csv writer: `writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")`

Comment: sorry for the wrong suggestion, didn't know we could do that

Comment: you should make the question simpler and post this as an answer.

Comment: okey, tried to make it a bit more simple now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, you can assign delimiter when initiating csv.writer

```
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
```